# Google Maps API for Work customers - API Requests

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the API for 'Work customers', I understand that I can make 100 000 requests per 24 hour period but I'm not sure which events invoke a request?

Example 1: I load a map with 10 markers on it. I do NOT geocode the markers location because the lng/lats was already known.

Total request to the API=1; (load the map)

Example 2: I load a map with 10 markers on it. I DO geocode the markers location for each marker and add it to the map;

Total request to the API=11; (load the map and geocode location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your daily quota depends on the details of your Maps for Work contract so I can't comment on that. However, what I can say is that geocoding requests from *within* the JS API do not count as requests. Rather, that are rate-limited per client.

Geocoding using the Web Service endpoint, however, does count against quota (but quota is complicated so it's not as simple as saying you have a single pool of 100000 requests or whatever).

Comment: Many thanks for the response, it seems it really is quite complicated.

Comment: Can you confirm, is this client or server side usage of the API.
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp?&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry,places"></script>
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

Comment: I see now that this is a client side request

Comment: Correct, that's a client-side request. Please consider accepting this answer if it resolves your query.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (with the free stuff) only the loading of the API itself counts as a usage. You can use all the other services without it having an affect on a query limit. However, the more queries you make from a service like Geocoding at a time, the more time is needed between queries to avoid a temporary OVER_QUERY_LIMIT (in terms of requests in short time-periods).

Therefore, Geocoding for markers will not affect your limit. However, it may take several seconds for all the points to load successfully.